# Scaling of web page depend upon device dimension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing an application for tablet where I have fixed container width of 500px and height of 800px. I can not keep the container size in percentage due to some restriction.

Due to this the page does not scale to device width(landscape or portrait).

I need to scale the complete container to device dimension.

Is there any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about media queries!

Comment: Check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Could you explain why you can't use a size in percentage?

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 500px) and (min-height: 800px) {
  .bloc {
       width : 500px;
       height : 800px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 768px) {
      .bloc {
           width : 1024px;
           height : 768px;
      }
    }
```

You can use media queries to know the size of your device and set width and height in css. You can find more ifnormations about media queries  on mozilla's forum : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your element in a DIV and try adding

```
max-width: 500px;
width: 100%;
```

to it so that it will scale dynamically to a max width of 500px. You can try [`@media` queries](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/an-introduction-to-css3-media-queries.html) to define specific CSS for viewport dimensions.